# Pass Java code to Python

Tags: python, python-bitcoinlib

I have a Java code that I need to pass to python but I don't know which libraries to use and how to start and if you can help me it is very grateful

MNEMONIC = "twenty four word mnemonic here"
ACCOUNT_KEY = ""
WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY = ""

// We'll generate 3 parameters here
// 1. hashedSecret
// 2. encryptedSecret
// 3. hashedPublicKey

const epochTimeNow = Date.now().toString()

const secret = getDeterministicTradeSecret(MNEMONIC, epochTimeNow) // This function in defined below
const hashedSecret = hash160(secret)

const encryptedSecret = encryptTradeSecret(
secret,
ACCOUNT_KEY,
undefined
)

const publicKey = privateKeyToPublic(privateKey)
const hashedPublicKey = hash160(publicKey)

const btc_trade_secrets = {
encrypted_secret: encryptedSecret,
hashed_secret: hashedSecret,
hashed_public_key: hashedPublicKey,
}

Comment: Hi you1977, sorry, we only collect English content on this site. If you would like to support this question, please help by translating it to English and flag for reopening.